# Django and oracle TypeError: environment can only contain strings

Tags: django, oracle

I have a project that I need to connect to an oracle database

When I use sqlite3 it brings by default with the following string:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

The application works without problems but when I connect with oracle with the following string:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
        'NAME': 'DBARS_PROD',
        'USER': 'userhere',
        'PASSWORD': 'passhere',


        }
}
```

Django gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 62, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 101, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in run
    autoreload.main(self.inner_run, None, options)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 332, in main
    reloader(wrapped_main_func, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 303, in python_reloader
    exit_code = restart_with_reloader()
  File "C:\Users\nbueno\Envs\nworksdev\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 289, in restart_with_reloader
    exit_code = subprocess.call(args, env=new_environ)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 523, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "c:\python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 959, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
TypeError: environment can only contain strings
```

But if I run the python command manage.py test to test the connection I devuleve that everything is correct:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Creating test user...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
Destroying test user...
Destroying test database tables...
```

It seems that when django queries oracle this returns unicode and not strings. Or does anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the solution, apparently it was the driver cx_oracle in its last version 6.0b1 ... I had connection problems, I simply downgraded to 5.2 again and everything worked fine